# number precision in C++

Tags: c++

I don't understand this code

```
double f(int a, double b){return a+b;}
int f(int c, int d){return c-d;}

int main() {
    int i = f(1,2.1F);
}
```

What does 2.1F mean? I thought that is precision, and the function which will be called will be int f. But I was wrong. It will call double f, why? Thank you very much.

Comment: See e.g. [this floating point reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal), read the section about *suffixes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `f` (or `F`) suffix makes the literal a `float` - which prefers to be converted to `double` as conversion to `int` would truncate it.

Answer (score 0):

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) covers the difference between numeric promotion and conversion.